# RSS Feeds: Using Aggregator (Drupal Core) vs Feeds module - which has more features and is more reliable?

Tags: 7, feeds

RSS Feeds: Using Aggregator (Drupal Core) vs Feeds module - which has more features and is more reliable?

It looks like Feeds has more features. Is this true? and is it more reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, I would be inclined to say Feeds module, on the basis of:

- more integration with other Drupal entities allowing more possibilities for manipulation of the content
- extensibility - ability to extend with extension modules that parse the XML content of the feed to re-purpose it. e.g. rather than a text list of youtube videos, the actual videos themselves embedded into the page
- standard api for extensions
- well supported and active in drupal 7